# Can I change the Application Developer field on Google's OAuth2 screen

Tags: oauth

On Google's OAuth2 screen, when it is asking for the set of permissions, there is a “Learn more” link. [image: Screenshot]

I would like the Application developer field to not show my email address, but rather my employer's website.

I know I could just create a generic email address, e.g. info@.... and have that be the application developer, but that is sub-optimal and involves creating a separate email address that could well require monitoring, etc...

Has anyone been able to control what gets displayed in this field?

### Update

Here is the create client id screen, [image] You will notice that the email address is not editable :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the email address that is displayed has to be that of an Owner of the project, and that any Owner can log in and elect to be that contact.

If another Owner of the project logs in and sees that second screen (where for you it says **you** for them it would not), it should give them an option to elect to become the public contact email displayed in the access grant page.

Comment: That at least lets me change the email address... but I believe it would have to be for a different gmail account... not a catch-all address or an alias for the group of developers supporting the app. I'd really prefer it to be an URL... but we'll see what we can do with the address idea

Comment: You could register <myapp>@gmail.com then set up a filter to automatically forward mail to your account or to a mailing list.